# AWS SAM Lambda typescript project doesnt attach to debugger in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I have used AWS SAM to initialize a typescript lambda project which I am editing in VSCode on Windows 10. I have also setup debug points in the typescript code and this is my launch.json

```
{
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "aws-sam",
            "request": "direct-invoke",
            "invokeTarget": {
                "target": "template",
                "logicalId": "HelloWorldFunction",
                "templatePath": "${workspaceFolder}/lambda-app/template.yaml"
            },
            "lambda": {
                "runtime": "nodejs14.x"
            },
            "sam": {
                "containerBuild": false,
                "skipNewImageCheck": false
            },
            "api": {
                "httpMethod": "get"
            },
            "name": "templatestyle"
        },
        {
            "type": "aws-sam",
            "request": "direct-invoke",
            "invokeTarget": {
                "target": "code",
                "lambdaHandler": "app.lambdaHandler",
                "projectRoot": "${workspaceFolder}/lambda-app/hello-world"
            },
            "lambda": {
                "runtime": "nodejs14.x",
                "payload": {
                    "json": {
                        "key1": "value1",
                        "key2": "value2",
                        "key3": "value3"
                    }
                }
            },
            "sam": {
                "containerBuild": false,
                "skipNewImageCheck": false
            },
            "api": {
                "httpMethod": "get"
            },
            "name": "basic"
        }
    ]
}
```

This is my tsconfig.json

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
      "target": "es2020",
      "strict": true,
      "preserveConstEnums": true,
      "noEmit": true,
      "sourceMap": true,
      "module":"es2015",
      "moduleResolution":"node",
      "esModuleInterop": true, 
      "skipLibCheck": true,
      "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,  
    },
    "include": ["*"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

This is the code in app.ts

```
import { APIGatewayProxyEvent, APIGatewayProxyResult } from 'aws-lambda';

/**
 *
 * Event doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html#api-gateway-simple-proxy-for-lambda-input-format
 * @param {Object} event - API Gateway Lambda Proxy Input Format
 *
 * Return doc: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/set-up-lambda-proxy-integrations.html
 * @returns {Object} object - API Gateway Lambda Proxy Output Format
 *
 */

export const lambdaHandler = async (event: APIGatewayProxyEvent): Promise<APIGatewayProxyResult> => {
    let response: APIGatewayProxyResult;
    try {
        response = {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'hello world',
            }),
        };
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
        response = {
            statusCode: 500,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                message: 'some error happened',
            }),
        };
    }

    return response;
};
```

When I select either of the debug configurations above, the break point only attaches in a file that is not part of what I created. It stops without a breakpoint on the first line below, which is seems to be in the path `\var\runtime\index.js`

[image]

Where did this file come from? Docker perhaps?. Also, why is it stopping here in this file and not in the breakpoint I put on my app.ts?
This is the result I get in the debug console, and the breakpoints I have set are not hit. How do I fix this?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

By default the debugger will break on the first line of code. There is a switch to disable this.  I don't see the command you are using for local invoke.  I was able to get it to break on my source code by using the following:

```
sam local invoke <function logical id> --event events/event.json -d <port>
```

Function logical id is the name of your function in template.yml and port is the debug port to use. I used 9999.  The command I used was

```
sam local invoke HelloWorldFunction --event events/event.json -d 9999
```

Comment: But thats not any line of code I wrote that it first breaks on. Also, I am not using sam local invoke. Since I am running this in VSCode I just select the appropriate debug configuration defined in the launch.json file and press F5 in VSCode

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I have the same issue with typescript handlers not attaching.